# Test environment for microsoft graph api and Azure v2.0

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, onenote, onenote-api

I am integrating OneNote application using MS graph endpoints. To authenticate the user I am using azure v2.0 endpoint. Does microsoft graph platform, onenote and azure provides test/sandbox environment the same.

Currently I am using endpoints as follows -

1. Fetch onenote notebooks - https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/notebooks
2. Authenticate user using Azure v2.0 - https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
   https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token

These endpoints works in all environment including dev/prod/test. The kind of application that we register at https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/ does that only matter ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

Yes - you can use the graph explorer as your test environment.

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_register_app_v2

Yes - the kind of application you register matters. If this is a new app, I'd recommend using a converged application so your app works for O365 and Microsoft accounts. See link above for full description.

Comment: So there is no difference between the endpoints that we are using for production and test environments ?

Comment: There is no test environment - only perhaps test accounts that you are using. You might also have a test appid and production appid, but the environment is always the same.

Comment: Great. Thanks you :)

Comment: No problem - you might want to mark the question as answered ;)

Comment: how to distinguish between  test appid and production appid.  Do we have same procedure for register app for both the environment. (i.e. production and test) as mentioned at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_register_app_v2

Comment: Yes, it is the same procedure. The distinction is which app have your users authorized?

Comment: Generally API limit varies as per environment . For production it's comparatively high.. this doesn't applies to graph API ?  And what is rate limit after which throttling is seen in graph API for onenote

Comment: I'd be interested in testing how my app using MS Graph API behaves under certain conditions, like getting HTTP 503, or HTTP 429 (being throttled), or socket timeout exceptions. Is there a way to induce & test failures for certain test accounts then? (I know this is a long shot, but I had to ask.)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the accepted answer, that Graph Explorer can be used for test purposes, you can also create Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) **sandbox** account and use it as completely separated Azure Portal test environment.

The sandbox account works under test domain (tenant). Like in standard Azure portal, you can register app (for SSO scenario).
You can also "install" test data, where the "installation" creates test random users as Microsoft accounts under the test domain (with the same shared password).

[image]